# REST GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl not working?

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm currently trying to retrieve folders and files from my sharepoint server and for that, I'm using RESTful calls. The problem is that the method GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl is not returning a list of folders nor files. I made some different calls like:

/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Relative Folder>')

/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Relative Folder>')/Folders

/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Relative Folder>')/Files

/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Relative Folder>')?$expand=Folders,Files

The server does recognize that the folder exists. However, i cannot list the files no the subfolders in there. The result is always a short xml with some links but with no useful information.

Can someone help me with this? What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Here`s the result when i access the /files link:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xml:base="[Site Api]">
  <id>46390b86-1167-4735-ba9e-880f06df0061</id>
  <title/>
  <updated>2017-10-14T13:56:31Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name/>
  </author>
</feed>
```

As you can see, it does return an empty xml file! What can be wrong?

Edit 2:

Here's something new: when i try to access a specific file using /files('file name') it returns me File Not Found exception. It's odd, since i'm the one who created it! But when I try to get the file with GetFileByServerRelativeUrl it does return me the file!

Answer (score 0):

I got the responses I was looking for when I fleshed out the URLs (more than I thought would be necessary:

https://Not.Really.Mine/Sitev2017/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/Sitev2017/Shared%20Documents/3. Testing/Integration Test Scripts')/files

What specifically are you looking for. It is possible that this is an expectation misalignment.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Does the response contains a list of the files of the folder? thats what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, but it is in the form of XML with all the metadata from the list. So it takes some parsing.

Comment: I updated my question with the results i get!